# Return Column index of the Active Cell so it can be manipulated to form a new Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a common cell where the calculation always starts then I want to translate the range depending on the date and how many weeks have passed since the spreadsheet was last updated.

for example Active Cell column index is 4 and 12 weeks have passed. So the Active Cell needs to now be column 16. Then I would like to select 12 Columns to the right and all used rows.

```
$ Sub DataUpdate()


Dim WeekCom As Double
Dim WeekUpd As Double
Dim DatSt As Range
Dim DifWks As Double


WeekCom = Int("WeekCommencing")
WeekUpd = Int("Lastupdate")
DifWks = WeekCom - WeekUpd
Set DatSt = Range("DataStart")

If WeekCom > WeekUpd + 7 Then
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(Cells(row(DatSt), = Column(DatSt)+ DifWks), Cells
           (Cells.Rowindex.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell), = Column(DatSt)+ DifWks+12))

End With

End If

End Sub $
```

This is what I have so far I'm not sure if it's any use as I am new to VBA.

Regards

Greg

```
Sub DataUpdate()

Dim WeekCom As Long
Dim WeekUpd As Long
Dim DifWks As Long
Dim DatSt As Range
Dim newRange As Range

**WeekCom = CInt(Range("WeekCommencing").Value)**
**WeekUpd = CInt(Range("Lastupdate").Value)**
DifWks = WeekCom - WeekUpd
Set DatSt = Range("DataStart")

If WeekCom > WeekUpd + 7 Then
    Set newRange = Intersect(DatSt.Offset(0, DifWks).Resize(1, DifWks).EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
End If

    MsgBox newRange.Address

End Sub
```

This code still seems to be providing an error of "Overflow". the only data it is currently using is dates formatted as general so up in the 40 thousands. @MacroMan_ Sorry to keep bothering you but I hope you can help. I have put asterisks around where it's showing an error. 
Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Intersect()`, `Offset()` and `Resize()` - I've assumed `DatSt` is a single cell in this scenario:

```
Sub DataUpdate()

Dim WeekCom As Integer
Dim WeekUpd As Integer
Dim DifWks As Integer
Dim DatSt As Range
Dim newRange As Range

WeekCom = CInt(Range("WeekCommencing").Value)
WeekUpd = CInt(Range("Lastupdate").Value)
DifWks = WeekCom - WeekUpd
Set DatSt = Range("DataStart")

If WeekCom > WeekUpd + 7 Then
    Set newRange = Intersect(DatSt.Offset(0, DifWks).Resize(1, DifWks).EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
End If

    MsgBox newRange.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Macro Man. I am also having trouble as I am getting a Run time error 13 with my code. Would you be able to help. Cheers

Comment: probably because you're using `row(DatSt)` where I think you want `DatSt.Row` there is also no need for the `=` in the `Range()` method. You don't need any of that though with this example.

Comment: I have copied in your code in place of my {with} section and the error seems to be appearing on the WeekCom = and WeekUpd = lines

Comment: You're trying to convert a string to an integer - assuming they are named ranges you need something like `CInt(Range("WeekCommencing").Value)` you've also declared those variables as `Double` which doesn't make any sense if you're casting them to Integers...

Comment: @MacroMan_ It seems to be showing an overflow message. I have changed the Integer types to Double but still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If you are working with whole numbers, change the `Integer` types to `Long`. `Double` is used for floating point calculations with decimal places.